# Obtain the Master Port Name of a Pseudo Terminal

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, pts

How do you get the master port name when I create a Pseudo Terminal? I know I can use `ptsname()` to obtain the slave port name but what about the master?

```
int fdm, fds;
char slave_port_name[256];
int open_res = openpty(&fdm, &fds, slave_port_name, NULL, NULL);

system("ls -l /dev/");
printf("Master Port Name: %s, file descriptor: %d\n", ??? How to get master portname?, fdm);
printf("Slave Port Name: %s, file descriptor: %d\n", slave_port_name, fds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't - there is no name for the master in the open_pt interface (there is a name for the masters in BSD style pty, however).  You can't "open" the master device a second time, but you can dup the fd and pass it around if you need to (why do you need to, though?)